# GROUP BY all columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, having

New to MySQL, couldn't find the right answer here.

I have these tables: Passengers, and Tickets. I need to show **all** the data of the passengers that bought 5 tickets, no just the ID

I've managed to do this, but I need all the data of the passengers.

```
SELECT Passenger.IdPassenger
FROM Passengers
JOIN Ticket ON Passenger.IdPassenger = Ticket.IdPassenger
GROUP BY Passenger.IdPassenger
HAVING COUNT(*) = 5;
```

The only way mysql let me show all the data of the passengers is doing SELECT * and then in the GROUP BY clause put EVERY column, is there a way to do a group by all like group by * ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use id's in subquery to get all data :

```
select *
  from Passengers p
 where p.IdPassenger in (select Ticket.IdPassenger
                           from Ticket
                          group by Ticket.IdPassenger
                         having count(*) = 5)
```

Comment: I assume you can have only tickets table in the subquery.

Comment: yes. i will update it

Answer (score 4):

`GROUP BY` the Tickets table in a *derived table*, to get 5 tickets id's. `JOIN`:

```
select p.*
from Passengers p
join (SELECT IdPassenger
      FROM Ticket
      GROUP BY IdPassenger
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 5) t
   ON p.IdPassenger = t.IdPassenger
```